# How do i display List<object> with items in console C#

Tags: c#, list, object, console

can someone please help me...
Im trying to display the items in the list on the console.

the current output is displaying my two sub classes: Grocery and FreshProduce.
I have also added a image showing the current result below.

any help is much appreciated.

```
namespace ShoppingList
{
    class ShoppingList
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Grocery myGrocery = new Grocery("Bread", 1);
            FreshProduce myFreshProduce = new FreshProduce("Orange", 1);

            List<object> myShoppingList = new List<object>();
            myShoppingList.Add(myGrocery);
            myShoppingList.Add(myFreshProduce);

            PrintValues(myShoppingList, '\t');

        }

        public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myList, char mySeparator)
        {
            foreach (Object obj in myList)
            Console.Write("{0}{1}", mySeparator, obj);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        public abstract class Product
        {
            protected string Name;
            protected int Quantity;
        }

        public class Grocery : Product
        {
            public Grocery(string groceryName, int groceryQuantity)
            {
                Name = groceryName;
                Quantity = groceryQuantity;
            }
        }
        public class FreshProduce : Product
        {
            public FreshProduce(string freshProduceName, int         freshProduceQuantity)
            {
                Name = freshProduceName;
                Quantity = freshProduceQuantity;
            } 

        }

    }
 }
```

[image: Current result]

Comment: Not addressing the issue necessarily, but seems to me like it would make more sense to have a common `Food` class or something that both `Grocery` and `FreshProduce` derive from and do `List<Food>` rather than doing `List<object>`

Comment: Use string.Join() method :             Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", myList.Select(x => x.Name + ":" + x.Quantity.ToString())));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to print the details of the `Product`, you should override the `ToString()` method. You can do this by using the below implementation of the `Product` class

```
public abstract class Product {
    protected string Name;
    protected int Quantity;

    public override string ToString() {
        return $"Name = {Name}, Quantity = {Quantity}";
    }
}
```

While I am at it, you might as well make some other minor improvements to your code. See the full code below

```
namespace ShoppingList {
    class ShoppingList {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Grocery myGrocery = new Grocery("Bread", 1);
            FreshProduce myFreshProduce = new FreshProduce("Orange", 1);

            List<Product> myShoppingList = new List<Product>();
            myShoppingList.Add(myGrocery);
            myShoppingList.Add(myFreshProduce);

            PrintValues(myShoppingList, "\t");
        }

        // instead of IEnumerable, you should use IEnumerable<Product> for better type checking
        public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable<Product> myList, string mySeparator) {
            // string.Join does exactly what you are trying to do using a loop
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(mySeparator, myList));
        }


        public abstract class Product {
            protected string Name;
            protected int Quantity;

            public override string ToString() {
                return $"Name = {Name}, Quantity = {Quantity}";
            }
        }

        public class Grocery : Product {
            public Grocery(string groceryName, int groceryQuantity) {
                Name = groceryName;
                Quantity = groceryQuantity;
            }
        }
        public class FreshProduce : Product {
            public FreshProduce(string freshProduceName, int freshProduceQuantity) {
                Name = freshProduceName;
                Quantity = freshProduceQuantity;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: im getting some errors:
invalid arguments on: PrintValues(myShoppingList, "\t");
invalid arguments on: Console.WriteLine(string.Join(mySeparator, myList));

Comment: also im trying to print this part:

        Grocery myGrocery = new Grocery("Bread", 1);
        FreshProduce myFreshProduce = new FreshProduce("Orange", 1);


its added in my list<object>

List<Product> myShoppingList = new List<Product>();
            myShoppingList.Add(myGrocery);
            myShoppingList.Add(myFreshProduce);

Comment: that's is not the problem

Comment: what version of VS are you using?

Comment: @user3775220 The full code copied verbatim works fine on VS2017

Comment: im downloading it now then ill get back to you.

Comment: @user3775220 check the working code at https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xhq9Jb

Comment: it works in VS2017...thank you very much  Vikhram